# Difference in Scope Variable in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, scope

```
tens=[]
for i in range(10,100,10):
    tens.append(i)
```

Result = `[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]`

```
for i in range(10,100,10):
    tens=[]
    tens.append(i)
```

Result = `[90]`

What is the actual code difference here ? And how the scope variable in this case differs each other ?

Comment: You're redeclaring tens each time through your loop, since range yeilds `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]` you're appending 90 in the last iteration

Comment: You "clear" the list every time in the loop by setting its value to `[]` in the second code snippet. In the first, you initialize it once before the loop and then add all the values

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the 'tens' variable is getting reset at the beginning of each loop, so on the last loop, it gets emptied and the last value of 'i' is appended.

In the first example, the variable is set outside the loop so doesn't get reset each time through.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you are initializing your list within your for loop, which you can easily see when it is written in the form:

```
for i in range(10,100,10):
 tens=[]
 tens.append(i)
```

as you can see, you empty your list during each step of the for loop. In your first example, you create the list *before* the for loop, so it doesn't get emptied.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case:

```
for i in range(10,100,10):
    tens = []
    tens.append(i)
```

You are assigning a new variable named `tens` to a new list, *each* iteration of the loop. That means you are creating several single-element lists, and adding a single value, to them, then discarding them by replacing them with a new list. When you check the value of `tens` after the loop, it then only has the last iteration, which was to create a list and append 90 to it.

In the first case:

```
tens = []
for i in range(10, 100, 10)
    tens.append(i)
```

In this case, you only assign to `tens` before the loop and then append several numbers to the list. If you check the value of `tens` after the loop, it has all of the values from the range.

This isn't really related to scope, more to the fact that you are overwriting `tens` to be a new list on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend to update your answer and to display the code appropriately. I am assuming this is what you mean:

```
tens=[] 
for i in range(10,100,10): 
    tens.append(i)

print(tens) # [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]

for i in range(10,100,10): 
    tens=[] 
    tens.append(i)

print(tens) # [90]
```

The difference is that in the second loop, you are overwriting the variable `tens` in every iteration, which leads to the output of only the final statement: [90]